# malformed array literal when saving to postgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

This one beats be as Im sure this worked before...not 100% sure. My form sends information, like this, to be saved in the db: `"a,b,c,d"` As a string. I want to convert that into an array before saving:

**model:**

```
before_validation :bar_to_array

...

def bar_to_array
 self.foo = foo.split(",").map do |n| n end
end
```

**controller:**

```
def new
 @x = @y.as_json(:only [:foo => [] ]) // passed to reactjs
end

private
  def x_params
   params.require(:x).permit(:foo => [])
  end
```

**postgres db:**

```
def change
  add_column :x, :foo, :text, array: true, default: []
end
```

**The array should be in the db as:**

```
[
  [0]a
  [1]b
  [2]c
  [3]d
]
```

Full error:

> ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{{}}" 
>   DETAIL:  Unexpected "}" character.

Comment: Have you tried `to_a` method?

Comment: `foo.split(",").map do |n| n end` work perfectly in the rails console.